# How do I include dependencies in the aar I created

Tags: android, gradle, aar

It doesn't contain the dependencies I used in the aar file I created. How do I include dependencies in aar?

Comment: Could you add more information on what exactly is your problem?
Do you have any error logs ?

Comment: I am using Retrofit in my library. When I export it as an AAR and try to use it, I get an error message saying 'Retrofit library not found'

Comment: Provide some code, I can't help you without an idea of you project/setup.